# В Python пройти три цикла с двумя условиями

Tags: python, циклы, if, условия

Мне требуется умножить и суммировать значения по формуле. Есть три цикла, бегущих по одному диапазону от 0 до 4. Формула `Σ Σ Π (q—l)`

1. основание левой суммы сначала перебираем по `j=0` (проходить `j` будем от [0, 1, 2, 3]);
2. тогда основание следующей суммы перебираем по `k!= 0` (то бишь `k`-диапазон [1, 2, 3], когда `j=0`);
3. в заключительном произведении `l!= 0` и `l!=k` (то есть если `k=1`, то `l` в диапазоне [2, 3] и тогда первое произведение получаем `(q—2)(q—3)`;
4. далее нам требуется перейти к `k=2`, и тогда следующее слагаемое для второй суммы `(q—1)(q—3)`;
5. после финального `k=3` переходим на следующую итерацию `j=1` (и так, пока не переберем все j в диапазоне [0, 1, 2, 3])).

В итоге должно получиться 12 слагаемых, где слагаемыми выступают произведения двух скобок `(q—l_1)(q—l_2)`.

Я написал код, но он не дает ничего (и ошибки тоже). Понятно, что я там поставил невыполнимое условие, отрицая **k** и **l**, хотя все три буквы бегут по одному диапазону.

Но как мне тогда быть? Как наложить ограничение, что если **j** равна нулю, то **k** не должна быть ноль, а **l** не должна нести текущее значение **j** и **k**? Ниже привел формулу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
from sympy import symbols
import math
q = symbols('q')
orders = 4
x_js_list = [0.1, 1.3, 5.2, 3.7, 4.9, 7.5]
# q=10 
for j in range(0, orders+1):
    if orders < len(x_js_list): # необязательное здесь условие
        for k in range(0, orders+1, -1):
            if k != j:
                for l in range(0, orders+1):
                    if l != k and l != j:
                        print(math.prod(q - l))
```

Comment: что-то сложно
а можете написать формулу (хотя бы картинкой) что именно надо вычислить

Comment: @Zhihar, выше формулу добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял задание, но что-то похожее получилось - сумма произведений `(q-l)` в различных сочетаниях

```
from sympy import symbols

q = symbols('q')
orders = 4
s = 0 # первая сумма
for j in range(0, orders):
    s1 = 0 # вторая сумма
    for k in range(0, orders):
        if k != j:
            m = 1 # произведение
            for l in range(0, orders):
                if l != k and l != j:
                    m *= q - l
            s1 += m
    s += s1
print(s)
```

```
2*q*(q - 3) + 2*q*(q - 2) + 2*q*(q - 1) + 2*(q - 3)*(q - 2) + 2*(q - 3)*(q - 1) + 2*(q - 2)*(q - 1)
```